# ASP.Net Application end unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables

My application's session is ending abruptly and I can't determine why. I've added significant logging throughout and there is no particular page causing the session end. I can see the session start and end by logging in the global.asa. I've used perfmon to monitor for application restarts and it shows none. Sometimes the session lasts 1 hour, sometimes 1 minute. The issue is so sporadic I can't recreate it.

I'm using InProc session mode with a timeout of 120. I see no events in the event log showing what might be the culprit. Running IIS 7.5. App pool idle timeout = 0, queue length =2000, recycle request limit=0. RapidFail is enabled with max failures of 5.

I excluded \%windir%\assembly, \%windir%\Microsoft.Net, \%windir%\system32\inetsrv from virus scans per MSDN [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akshayns/archive/2008/09/29/common-reasons-for-the-session-loss-issue-in-asp-net-applications.aspx).

--EDIT--

After research, found application is recycling. Added [healthmonitor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx) tags in machine.config for event logs and only see 'Application is Starting' events. My logging in the global.asa>Application_End event is rarely fired. When it does it states: 'Change Notification for critical directories.  bin dir change or directory rename' but can't see the change.

Running process monitor, I see these reg entries read right before the app dies.
[image]

Comment: How do you know your session is ending?  Are there session variables that all of sudden go blank?

Comment: Yes. They go blank and I'm logging on session end.

Comment: I suggest you put some logging in Application_End in global to see if you are getting restarts that are not showing up in perfmon for some reason.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks

Comment: Are any files under your web application being touched or added/deleted.  Possibly a virus scanner that may be causing your problem?

Comment: Good point. I forgot to add my virus scanner exclusion, but it's still happening. Added to question for clarity.  We do have an app that copies files to the web but it hasn't copied anything for at least a week. The session drop has happened 25 times today alone.

Comment: Note that IIS can stop the app pool at any time when no active connections are detected within a certain time period.  This can occur before your configured session timeout.

Comment: My idle timeout in the app pool is 0. My understanding is 0 will turn that off, correct?

Comment: After adding logging on Application Start in global.asa, yes, it's restarting every couple of minutes. How do I determine the cause?

Comment: After adding logging (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx), found app is restarting but the application_end event is rarely called, which is where the best data is. I only see the 'Application is starting' events. Why would this event not be called? Also, right before it dies, I see these reg entries read (see image above)